# training fit in echostatenet

Tags: echo, pytorch, data-fitting

I am using an Echo-state-net code implemented on PyTorch, and even though the prediction is accurate enough, the training fit looks shifted, can someone help to understand why this can happen? The shift function is deactivated in the code.
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkQI3.png)

Comment: Please, add a short bit of code including the loss function and provide some info about the picture you posted (what each line is, what each axis refers to..)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the code I am using is from https://github.com/cknd/pyESN. I copied the pyESN.py file and used these lines to train my model (the curve in the example is a generic exponential with some noise applied, on horizontal axis there is time and on the vertical axis the corresponding values of the exponential function, I used it as just an example)

Comment: `trainlen = 80`  
`future = 5`  
`futureTotal=len(y)-trainlen`  
`pred_tot=np.zeros(futureTotal)`  

`for i in range(0,futureTotal,future):`  
    `pred_training = esn.fit(np.ones(trainlen),data[i:trainlen+i])`  
    `prediction = esn.predict(np.ones(future))`  
    `pred_tot[i:i+future] = prediction[:,0]`